# How to get data from child component to parent component when save button in parent component is clicked?

Tags: angular

I have a save button in parent compoenent. When I click on it the data in  child component should also get saved. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no effort shown to solve the issue.

Comment: You need to provide your code. What did you already tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@Input()`  and `@Output`

Answer (score -1):

Please look at [these](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component) docs on the Angular website. You will need an `@Output()`.
Essentially what will happen is in your save button in your child component it will call the save() method which can look like this: `this.newItemEvent.emit(value);` where `newItemEvent` is `@Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();`. Then you listend to `newItemEvent` in your parent component much like you listen to the `(click)` event for a button. For the complete example please look at [this](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component) tutorial.